# Creating a Xamarin Android F# project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

Visual Studio 2015, Update 3.

Create a blank solution. Choose Add New Project -> Visual F# -> Android.

Create either a Blank App (Android) or a Unit Test App (Android).

The app is created successfully.

Right click on References, and choose "Add Reference". The following dialog box pops up:

[image]

Note that when you look at the Project Properties, there are two "Application" tabs. The second one generates an error:

[image]

Once the project has been unloaded, it can no longer be reloaded. The resulting error message is:

[image]

I have reported this on the Xamarin Forums, but the process is slow. I'd like to find a workaround, but I'm fumbling in the dark. Once I've unloaded the `fsproj` file, I can't find any mention of "frameworkName", and I can't reload it either.

My Android settings appear to all be up to date:

[image: Android Settings]

Does anyone know of any workarounds that will allow me to start unit testing my existing app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have a fix for this issue :)

Xamarin expects F# 3.x to be present, which at this point must be manually added. You should be able to download F# 3.x [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=261286)

Please let me know if this fixes the issue for you.

Thanks!

Edit: I have filed the following bug as well: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42970

Comment: Job done.

I wouldn't have figured that out on my own. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped! I am going to follow up and file a bug. I will edit my answer with the link just to close the loop

Comment: This will be good. As it is at the moment, I can't install the FsUnit.xUnit NuGet package into the new test project, which is only a minor inconvenience, as Xunit installs without a hitch.

Comment: I will play around that as well. Hope you enjoy F# :D